Почему не подключаются шрифты на вордпрессе?
Натягивала готовый код на вордпресс, попробовала уже все способы, шрифт не меняется на сайте вордпресс, снизу пример того, что делала.
Шрифт лежит в папке assets, через функции не получилось подключить, через css тоже.
Помогите пожалуйста.



Подключайте шрифт отсюда https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat

Ну проверьте где находится CSS фаил, в котором вы прописали путь - ./assets/font/ - вполне возможно, что путь то такой например - ../assets/font/ или ../../assets/font (какая вложенность файлов то?). И может ttf не отрабатывает, вы бы подключали паралельно ещё хотя бы woff или woff2

Для начала изучаем Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?. Затем про то, как нужно писать ссылки в ВП (да и в css тоже), потом  как подключать скрипты и стили и в конце-концов про "натягивание".
